# Dynamic html link (href) code in php variable which is being used as a text for a sms

Tags: php, html, sms

I have a scenario, where I am running a SMS campaign where in each sms contains some text with a link. This link is dynamic and is different for each sms based on the user.
My SMS content - "Dear user, please [click here](http://linkgoesheere.com) to perform the activity. "

Below is the code I am using.

```
$smsusername = 'xxxxxx';
$smspassword = 'xxxxxx';
$destination = $phone;
$url = "http://www.example.com/?id=1" 
$source = 'SENDER-NM';
$text1 = 'Dear User, Please ';
$parturl = '<a href="$url">click here </a>';
$text2 = 'to perform the activity.';

$text = $text1 . $parturl . $text2;

$content =  'action=sendsms'.
            '&user='.rawurlencode($smsusername).
            '&password='.rawurlencode($smspassword).
            '&to='.rawurlencode($destination).
            '&from='.rawurlencode($source).
            '&text='.rawurlencode($text);

$smsglobal_response = file_get_contents('http://www.smsglobal.com.au/http-api.php?'.$content);

$explode_response = explode('SMSGlobalMsgID:', $smsglobal_response);
```

I feel there are no errors in this but still the SMS i am getting is something like this - [image]

Where I am I doing a mistake here. Please advise

Comment: seems to be that your sms sent as a plain text, provide more details about your SMS api or contact that api support team.

Comment: @hassan : I am using smsglobal's api here to send the sms. Here is the documentation of it - http://smsglobal.com/http-api/?_ga=2.244836549.1944820390.1495353526-723294973.1495033748

Comment: it's hard to find any clue about sending HTML contents there, I don't think that they are supporting HTML , even with email-api https://www.smsglobal.com/services/ , you will find "Ensure the body of the message is plain text, not HTML."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured that the SMS is being sent in plain text from the SMS Gateway provider only.
The solution I used is using bitly short link api -

```
$short_url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=mylogin&apiKey=myapikey&longUrl=".urlencode("$url")."&format=json"))->data->url;
```

and creating the sms content like this -

```
$text = $text1 . $short_url . $text2;
```

My final text looks like this -

> Dear User, Please visit http://shortlurllink and perform the activity.

which does the same work which I wanted earlier so I get what I wanted. :)

Thanks for the start @hassan.